# Can't ping some IP addresses in the same subnet (LAN) Windows 2011 Server

Tags: windows, ip, ping, local-area-network

Hi I’m running in Windows Small Server 2011 server standard (192.168.1.108), it’s my dhcp and dns server too, but suddenly all other users can’t get internet. My gateway is 192.168.1.1.

After a lots of tested I can saw that my server can’t get into the router (192.168.1.1), and also into some others computers, but some other computers answer the ping command. In fact the same computer with the IP 192.168.1.9 didn't answer, but with the IP 192.168.1.63, it response!

I have no routers, firewall, vlans or anything that disallow the traffic between computers, in fact when I changed the server IP address (192.168.1.109), I be able to ping the other computers and gateway, but if a back to the 192.168.1.108 the trouble comeback.

I hope you can help me with this issue

Ricardo

Comment: You need to see if any other devices on your network are trying to use the same IP address of your server.  It seems like you have a conflict.

Comment: What's your network layout? Are any devices wireless? Are you configuring IPs statically or using DHCP?

Answer (score 3):

Check to see that you don't have DHCP running on the "gateway" and on the server.  Also, check your DHCP on the server and make sure it is giving out 192.168.1.1 as teh default gateway.  Generally, SBS wants to be the router so it will give out itself as the gateway address.  "ipconfig /all" on a workstation should give you the IP of the DHCP server as well as the default gateway.  Also, make sure it isn't a DNS issue.  the gateway might be giving out public DNS servers which won't respond correctly to local domain names.  so when you go to ping using the hostname, it will respond with the wrong IP or no IP at all.

Comment: I once had a similar issue and realized one of the developer activated the DHCP server on his laptop.

Comment: I've had this happen too where people have plugged in wireless routers and they begin handing out IPs on the network as well.  One of the main reasons I no longer use 192.168.1.x or 192.168.0.x.  Makes it easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DHCP leases. It's quite possible that 192.168.0.108 has been given to another computer if you haven't set up the DHCP right. If that is the case, you need to exclude that particular IP-address from the DHCP-scope.